# Gettin Exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.lowagie.text.Element when generated pdf using openpdf-1.3.30.jar

Tags: java, string, itext, openpdf

I have replaced itext-2.1.0.jar with openpdf-1.3.30.jar because of the securities risks present in itext. I'm getting the below error when pdf is getting generated:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.lowagie.text.Element

Below is my code which I think is causing this issue:

```
        float[] columnWidths = { 2, 2, 8 };
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
        
        table.setSpacingBefore(40);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        
        PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(logtime, font));
        c1.setFixedHeight(17);
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(event, font));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        
        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(description, font));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);
        table.setHeaderRows(1);
```

when i searched the internet i got this (https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/issues/274)
not sure if this is my case.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this issue?

My pdf looks like this :

----Sample Output --------

-x-x-x-x Some info present here -x-x-x-x-x-

---

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

-x-x-x-x End of Pdf -x-x-x-x-x

Note :- Number of columns are fixed and rows are dynamic

I tried hard coding the Element.ALIGN_CENTER but it did not work then i got to know the issue is in Phrase class of openpdf jar

Comment: a String won't pass an IS-A check for Element, so you can't directly cast it, as the error is telling you. Likely, somewhere where you're casting, you need to map the value instead

Comment: this issue is coming in openpdf library i think not in my code

Comment: Please share the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: im only getting this error,no stack trace is there

Comment: There is usually always a stacktrace. Execute your code in an IDE and you'll see it.